# Were the scenes revolving The Night King heavily inspired by The Lich King in Warcraft?

Tags: game-of-thrones, reference

During Game of Thrones season 8, I couldn't help but notice the similarities between the concept of **The Night King** and **The Lich King** from Warcraft. A Frozen undead king that lives in a Northern arctic place (Northrend vs north beyond the Wall), commands an army of wights/ghouls and leads a group of frozen undead warriors who can use lesser forms of his necromancy that command his undead army (Death Knights vs White Walkers). And to further convince myself that this couldn't be all random, I just found out in The Frozen Throne expansion of Warcraft 3, at the climax of that game, the final mission, where Arthas(not yet the Lich King), would have his final showdown with Illidan Stormrage, the name of the mission is **"A Symphony of Frost and Flame"**. That's too specific and too close to **"A song of Ice and Fire"** to be a coincidence. I am not sure which character came first but it's not far-fetched to think one has been inspired by the other.

[image]

However, for this question, I'm more interested in how the show makers of GoT Season 8, chose to **represent** The Night King and his actions visually. If you watch the World of Warcraft, Wrath of the Lich King [cinematic trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HInmEcbFyF0) (2008), there are certainly moments that you will find familiar to the scenes in the show. For example, how **The Night King** resurrects one of Daenerys' dragons (an icy, undead king, surrounded by his army revives a blue-eyed dragon from a frozen lake) is very similar to what happens in the cinematic. And then there's this scene:
[image]

Is it fair to assume that those visuals in Season 8 were heavily inspired by **The Lich King**? The Lich King story was a great success among (World of) Warcraft fans, and probably the most sought-after character in its entire universe. So it does make a lot of sense for the show makers to actually take inspiration from a character that had resonated with a huge audience in the past. Do you think that was the case?

Comment: In terms of 'which character came first' it's the Night King, first mentioned in 2000, in A Storm of Swords, 4 years before Warcraft. However, because the TV show ran a long way ahead of the books, he's never been seen in the books. That would make his first visual appearance on TV in GoT S04 in 2014. [I know that doesn't get anywhere near an answer;)

Comment: Yeah if "The Frozen Throne" came out in 2003, its "A Symphony of Frost and Flame" is almost certainly a knowing reference to the "A Song of Ice and Fire" books, the first of which (A Game Of Thrones) came out in 1997 (and was an award-winning cult favourite long before the TV show came out in 2011). The part about what inspired the visuals may be hard to prove, but I strongly suspect the similarities are less "which one inspired the other" and more "what fantasy archetypes and artwork from decades ago inspired both"

Comment: I suspect it's like the authors of The Expanse reply when people ask them if they stole the idea of Belters from Larry Niven: No, we both stole from Alfred Bester.

Comment: tbh, everybody has some kind of 'king of the dead' from Tolkien to Pirates of the Caribbean ;)

Comment: Unless, showrunners are big fans to these games, the answers is just **no**. AFAICT this is just wishful thinking - if you got a hammer everything looks like a nail.

Comment: As others have commented, much more likely that both were inspired by a third property than one inspiring the other. Dungeons & Dragons, for example, draws heavily from many mythologies and folk tales and forms part of the gestalt that has led to these fantasy tropes.

Comment: While there might be some inspirations (and if so, it was most probably W3 inspired by ASOIAF books) most similarities can be explained by the fact that connection between necromancy and coldness is a common fantasy trope (most probably related to the fact that dead bodies are, well, cold).